# How to use stores and props in onMounted Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-composition-api, pinia, vue-props

I'm new in Vue Composition API and some functions as defineProps are not available. So, I have a following problem: from parent component I've got props and want to store in "Pinia" storage after a few calculations. How can I do it?

```
export default defineComponent({
  props: ['props'],
  setup() {
    const errorsStore = useErrorsStore();
   
    onMounted(() => {
      const status = (props) => {
        console.log(props);
        errorsStore.List.unshift(props);
        setInterval(status, 10000)
      }
      status(props);
    });
    return {
      errorsStore,
    };
  },
});
```

I'll be glad, if you answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not suggest to use the Vue predefined names, like `props` to name `variables`/`props`/`events` in Vue, since you will possibly have a conflict and it will be hard to clarify what's going on.

So, I have changed `props: ['props']` to `props: ['data']`

Here is a very basic example with Pinia

```js
const { createApp } = Vue
const { createPinia, defineStore, storeToRefs } = Pinia

const useErrorsStore = defineStore('ErrorsStore', 
{
  state: () => {
    return {
      List: []
    }
  },
  actions: {
   add(data) {
      data && this.$state.List.unshift(data) 
    }
  }  
})

const MyComp = {
  props: ['data'],
  setup(props) {
    const store = useErrorsStore()        
    console.log(props);
    store.add(props.data);    
    return {    
      store
    }
  },
  template: '{{store.List}}' 
}

const App = {
  components: { MyComp },
  setup() {
    const store = useErrorsStore()
    return {
      store
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
const pinia = createPinia()
app.use(pinia)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app">
  MyComp: <my-comp :data="{ item: 1 }"></my-comp>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-demi@0.13.11/lib/index.iife.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pinia@2.0.30/dist/pinia.iife.js"></script>
```